# woocommerce update broke development website?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I can't access admin dashboard or any pages on the frontend.. just blank page and view source is also blank.  I've enabled error reporting in php.ini and still a blank page.  I renamed both the theme name and deleted the woocommerce plugin and yet still blank pages.

How do i solve this?  Can't even view errors? This is caused by updating woocommerce.

Comment: What happens if you switch to default theme of wordpress and deactivate all plugins ?

Comment: can only access ftp.

Comment: I would suggest you to check locally if you have back up database and files.So that known issue can be found.

Comment: How would i know where to search for the error?

Comment: Its long process since you don't know the exact point from which it started occuring the error. First deactivate all plugins and revert back to default theme. After that activate plugin one by one so that you will get to know either woocommerce making an issue or something else ..

Comment: One more thing **NEVER UPDATE ANY PLUGIN OR THEME WITHOUT HAVING BACKUP**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG`. This will show you errors.

   `define('WP_DEBUG', true);

   define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);`

See [debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)
This will be important for determine where the error is coming from. 9 times out of 10, if you are having a problem when you upgrade WooCommerce it is because your theme is bundling out of date templates.

2. Use FTP to rename the `wp-content/plugins` folder to `wp-content/plugins-backup`. Renaming the plugins folder effectively deactivates all plugins.
3. Additionally, rename your current theme folder to anything else. Though I have found this doesn't always reset your site to a default theme.
4. In the case where this doesn't automatically reset your theme, in PHPmyadmin navigate to your `wp_options` table and edit the values of 1. current_theme, 2. template, and 3. stylesheet to be `twentyfourteen`.